# MySQL - partial search

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

Anybody knows how to search the partial words in database.

For Example -

My String is **Twenty-first Century Fox**

Database column value is **21st Century Fox**

How do I get result using MySQL LIKE or LOCATE or any other query?

What I want to match is - "st Century Fox"

Comment: `WHERE Column LIKE'%twenty-first%' OR Column LIKE'%century%' OR Column LIKE'%fox%'`.

Comment: You should look into full text search:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: I use fulltext search my all of my projects that require creating a search that's similar to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should investigate `FULLTEXT` searching; it's designed to find stuff like `fox` in `21st Century Fox`.  It involves creating a special-purpose index and then searching using a `MATCH()` predicate.

But understanding that `21st` and `Twenty-first` are equivalent is a more complex task. That involves lists of synonyms or other sources of knowledge. If you have to do this you should investigate Sphinx or Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

Use Soundex function campare the two strings...

```
<?php
$str = "Twenty-first Century Fox";
$str1 = "21st Century Fox";
echo soundex($str);
echo soundex($str1);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution would be breaking the string to number of words and search using `OR` and `LIKE`. In this case.

```
$keyword  = 'Twenty-first Century Fox';
$keywords = explode($keyword,' ');

$keySearch = array();
foreach ($keywords as $keyword){
    $keySearch[] = 'column LIKE \'%'.$keyword.'%\'';
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE '.implode(' OR ',$keySearch);
```